# Why won't my android phone charge from my computers USB port? It actually seems to drain the battery

Tags: nexus-5, google

Why won't my Android phone charge from my computers USB port and why does it seem it actually drains my battery?

Comment: Many devices will use more power than that supplied by a low-power USB port.  Have you tried other ports or other computers?  Does the device battery icon indicate that it's charging?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Matthew's comments, from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB):

> As with previous USB versions, USB 3.0 ports come in low-power and
>   high-power variants, providing 150 mA and 900 mA respectively, while
>   simultaneously transmitting data at SuperSpeed rates.[25]
>   Additionally, there is a Battery Charging Specification (Version 1.2 –
>   December 2010), which increases the power handling capability to 1.5 A
>   but does not allow concurrent data transmission.[22] The Battery
>   Charging Specification requires that the physical ports themselves be
>   capable of handling 5 A of current[citation needed] but limits the
>   maximum current drawn to 1.5 A.

In other words, it's worth it to try as many sources as you can find when looking for a good charging port.